# Where can I find the full forms of abbreviations used in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

Examples:

CV_8UC3
V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV
CV_YUV2BGR_YUYV

Where can I find the full forms of abbreviations used in OpenCV? What do I need to search in Google to know about them?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/master/

Comment: The types can be found with Google 'CV_8UC3 meaning' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183946/what-does-cv-8uc3-and-the-other-types-stand-for-in-opencv the other things are more function specific like CV_YUV2BGR_YUYV which looks like a color conversion code (because left and right of the 2 is a colorc space abbreviation. See cv::cvtColor for detail. You'll need some general imaging experience (BGR/RGB/YUV etc.). Googling V4L2 looks like this is related to video 4 linux api.

Comment: @Micka thanks, that was helpful. Try to write a detailed answer please.