# What format should I use for a Opencv image if I need to access the underlaying data?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencl

I've made a program that creates images using OpenCL and in the OpenCL code I have to access the underlaying data of the opencv-image and modify it directly but I don't know how the data is arranged internally.

I'm currently using `CV_8U` because the representation is really simple 0 black 255 white and everything in between but I want to add color and I don't know what format to use.

This is how I currently modify the image `A[y*width + x] = 255;`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `A[y*width + x] = 255;` works fine, then the underlaying image data A must be a 1D pixel array of size width * height, each element is a `cv_8u` (8 bit unsigned int).

Comment: But I want to add color and I don’t know which other format to use

Comment: That was not clear in your original question. Since you are using CV_8U, then the pixel format is 8 bit unsigned int, just simple gray scale. There are CV_8uc3 etc, where the 'c3'  specifies there are three channels, usually RGB. Then your 1D array should be 3 * width * height, ```A[y*width*3 + x * 3 + 0]``` will be the R, ```A[y*width*3 + x * 3 + 1]``` the G, ```A[y*width*3 + x * 3 + 1]``` the B. There might be ways to make a 2D or even 3D array for this, but in the end it is usually just a big chunk of linear memory.

Comment: Thanks that’s just what I needed the C3 thing is the thing I needed, very intuitive now that I see it. Just one thing If I understand correctly each color is a byte from 0-255 or it has 3 bytes per pixel? I think is the later.

Comment: Asking new questions or thing that were not mentioned. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183946/what-does-cv-8uc3-and-the-other-types-stand-for-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

The color values of a pixel, in the case of OpenCV, will be arranged `B G R` in memory. RGB order would be more common but OpenCV likes them BGR.

Your data ought to be `CV_8UC3`, which is the case if you use `imread` or `VideoCapture`. if it isn't that, the following information needs to be interpreted accordingly.

Your array index math needs to expand to account for the data's layout:

```
[(y*width + x)*3 + channel]
```

3 because 3 channels. `channel` is 0..2, x and y as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you'd need to convert this single-channel image to a 3-channel image to have color. The 3 channels are Blue, Green, Red (BGR).

OpenCV has a method that does just this, [cv2.cvtColor()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab), this method takes an input image (in this case the single channel image that you have), and a conversion code (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0) for more).

So the code would be like the following:

```
color_image = cv2.cvtColor(source_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Then you can modify the color by accessing each of the color channels, e.g.

```
color_image[y, x, 0] = 255 # this changes the first channel (Blue)
```

Comment: OP states that they use OpenCL and imply that they write their own OpenCL kernel. OpenCL doesn't support that indexing syntax.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you're probably right. This answer is to help point out what to do and provide a general direction. Since there's an 'opencv' tag on the question, I went ahead with OpenCV syntax. Have a nice day.