# How to match the color models of BufferedImage and Mat?

Tags: java, image, opencv

I'm trying to convert [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to [`Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) for a large set of images with different file types downloaded from the internet. Because I am scraping the images from websites, I have no control over the file formats. I can easily load them to `BufferedImage` without knowing the format, but to convert them to `Mat`, I need to know the image type. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a nice correspondence between `CvType` and `BufferedImage` types.

`CvType` represents image types with the format `CV_<bit-depth>{U|S|F}C<number_of_channels>` where `U` is unsigned char, `S` is signed char, and `F` is float.

`BufferedImage` types have more variety in the representation including a symmetrical channels ([`TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR)), varying numbers of bits ([`TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_BINARY)), and whatever an indexed byte image is ([`TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED)).

Based on the documentation, I tried to complete my own correspondence.

```
BufferedImage imgBuffer = ImageIO.read(new File("example.gif"));

//Save file as reference
File outputfile = new File("temp/image.png");
ImageIO.write(imgBuffer, "png", outputfile);

//My correspondance
int curCVtype = -1;
switch (imgBuffer.getType()) {
case BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8UC3;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8UC1;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR:
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8SC3;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8SC4;
    break;
default:
//  The types not handled by my correspondence
//                  BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;
//                  BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY;
//                  BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR;
//                  BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE;
//                  BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED;
//                  BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM;

    System.out.println("Unsupported format:" + imgBuffer.getType());
    //Here I choose a default type
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8SC3;
}

//Convert to Mat
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) imgBuffer.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Mat img = new Mat(imgBuffer.getHeight(), imgBuffer.getWidth(), curCVtype);
img.put(0, 0, pixels);

//Write the output to compare
Imgcodecs.imwrite("temp/image_mat.png", img);
```

### Questions

1. Am I going about this correctly? Or is there a better approach?
2. What are the correct correspondences for the types that are in my default case?

### Examples

Input 
 
[image: Input example gif]

Converted to PNG by `BufferedImage` 
 
[image: Reference BufferedImage]

Output PNG after conversion to Mat. `BufferedImage` type was`TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` converted to `CvType.CV_8SC3` 
 
[image: Mat output]

Output PNG after conversion to Mat. `BufferedImage` type was`TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` converted to `CvType.CV_8UC3` 
 
[image: Mat output]

### Resources:

My starting code came from [Converting BufferedImage to Mat in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958643/converting-bufferedimage-to-mat-in-opencv) .

What I know about CvTypes came from [What's the difference between cvtype values in OPENCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428689/whats-the-difference-between-cvtype-values-in-opencv) .

Comment: TYPE_INT should map to CV_32S, not CV_8S. Then TYPE_BYTE_BINARY to CV_8UC1, TYPE_USHORT_GRAY to CV_16UC1, TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR to CV_8UC4. And use CV_8UC3 as default

Comment: @Miki I initially thought the same about the int types, but was later confused by the documentation which says "Represents an image with 8-bit RGB color components packed into integer pixels." Just to clarify, the colors only require 8-bits, but they are stored as 32-bits?

Comment: _packed into integer pixels_ , so you need CV_32S. I don't know BufferedImage, but I think that you can convert all buffered images to RGB. Then you can just convert to opencv as if type was TYPE_3BYTE_BGR

Comment: @Miki Thanks, I think your comments would make a good answer.

Comment: Note that `TYPE_CUSTOM` isn't a single type, it is used to represent everything that is not one of the other types. You could probably create a direct conversion for all the known types, then a fallback using `getRGB` to `CV_8UC4` or `CV_32U` (I don't think any of the Java `TYPE_INT_xxx` should be treated as signed) which will be slower, but still fully compatible.

Comment: Have you tried just loading them from the file system directly to a Mat with Imgcodecs.imread() (opencv 3.0) or its equivalent in 2.4.x?  Or do you need to get them into a BufferedImage first?

Comment: @medloh BufferedImage has more supported file formats then Imgcodecs.imread(). Specifically, Imgcodecs.imread() cannot handle .gif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Miki and haraldK for the helpful comments.

My solution for unknown image types retrieves the pixels in RGB format, and put them into a `Mat` of `CvType.CV_8UC4` . Finally, reorder the channels using [`Core.mixChannels`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels) to the OpenCV prefered order: BGR(A).

This example only reorders the channels for the unknown image types, but all non BGR image types would need to be reordered.

```
BufferedImage imgBuffer = ImageIO.read(new File("example.gif"));

//Save image as reference
File outputfile = new File("temp/image.png");
ImageIO.write(imgBuffer, "png", outputfile);

//My correspondance

int curCVtype = CvType.CV_8UC4; //Default type
boolean supportedType = true;

switch (imgBuffer.getType()) {
case BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8UC3;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY:
case BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8UC1;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR:
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_32SC3;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_32SC4;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_16UC1;
    break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR:
case BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE:
    curCVtype = CvType.CV_8UC4;
    break;
default:
    // BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED;
    // BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM;
    System.out.println("Unsupported format:" + imgBuffer.getType());
    supportedType = false;
}

//Convert to Mat
Mat img = new Mat(imgBuffer.getHeight(), imgBuffer.getWidth(), curCVtype);
if (supportedType) {
    // Insert pixel buffer directly
    byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) imgBuffer.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    img.put(0, 0, pixels);
} else {
    // Convert to RGB first
    int height = imgBuffer.getHeight();
    int width = imgBuffer.getWidth();
    int[] pixels = imgBuffer.getRGB(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, null, 0, width);

    // Convert ints to bytes
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(pixels.length * 4);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    intBuffer.put(pixels);

    byte[] pixelBytes = byteBuffer.array();

    img.put(0, 0, pixelBytes);

    // Reorder the channels for Opencv BGRA format from
    // BufferedImage ARGB format
    Mat imgMix = img.clone();
    ArrayList<Mat> imgSrc = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    imgSrc.add(imgMix);

    ArrayList<Mat> imgDest = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    imgDest.add(img);

    int[] fromTo = { 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0 }; //Each pair is a channel swap
    Core.mixChannels(imgSrc, imgDest, new MatOfInt(fromTo));
}

//Save output image
Imgcodecs.imwrite("temp/image_mat.png", img);
```

The new output image
[image: Output image]

Comment: I'm using Javacv there is no Matofint(int...a) function in it.

Comment: @AqeelHaider The standard Java bindings to include it (http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/MatOfInt.html)

Comment: I use IplImage to load image.
use cvResize() method to resize it. 
Convert the Image to buffered Image to make the image corners round. and use TYPE_INT_ARGB 
Then convert it back to Mat to do perspective Transform. 
convert it back to buffered image to merge with another image. 
and then save it. 

Problem come when i convert image from buffer to Mat its colour change.

Comment: if i use TYPE_3BYTE_BGR in buffered image and then convert it Mat then colors didn't change, but it remove the background transparency of image to back.