# What's the difference between Vector_Point_to_Mat and Vector_Point2f_to_Mat

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using **Xamarin.OpenCV.Droid**,

and I'd like to convert an array of `Point`s to `Mat`.

I know `Converters` class has several methods that seem adequate for the conversion.

However, I totally don't understand the difference between `Vector_Point_to_Mat` and `Vector_Point2f_to_Mat`.

Both methods receive `Point[]` as an arg and return `Mat`.

What's the difference?

Which is more adequate to execute `Imgproc.GetPerspectiveTransform` for example?

https://github.com/NAXAM/opencv-android-binding/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C++ version, there are int, int64, float, and double based Point types.

```
typedef Point_<int> Point2i;
typedef Point_<int64> Point2l;
typedef Point_<float> Point2f;
typedef Point_<double> Point2d;
```

In the Java-based OpenCV, there is only `Point` (double-based), but the Java  vector_Point(|2d|2f)_to_Mat APIs will create a Mat with the corresponding CvType (via the native/C++ call) :

```
CvType.CV_32SC2 (vector_Point_to_Mat)
CvType.CV_32FC2 (vector_Point2f_to_Mat)
CvType.CV_64FC2 (vector_Point2d_to_Mat)
```

For info on types: see this SO: [What's the difference between cvtype values in OPENCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428689/whats-the-difference-between-cvtype-values-in-opencv)

```
public static Mat vector_Point_to_Mat(List<Point> pts) {
    return vector_Point_to_Mat(pts, CvType.CV_32S);
}

public static Mat vector_Point2f_to_Mat(List<Point> pts) {
    return vector_Point_to_Mat(pts, CvType.CV_32F);
}

public static Mat vector_Point2d_to_Mat(List<Point> pts) {
    return vector_Point_to_Mat(pts, CvType.CV_64F);
}
```

re: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2c6f1ab57d4250ee46e32d1b51c056431965b470/modules/java/generator/src/java/org/opencv/utils/Converters.java#L37

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I totally understand.